# LibVLC for Unity cannot load RTSP Flux on build

Tags: unity-game-engine, libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

I'm trying to get to display an RTSP flux on a canvas via the LibVLCSharp for Unity, and it works perfectly in editor mode. But when i'm building my app, it's not displaying my RTSP Flux and the logs indicate that no modules are found for RTSP (the same message also appears for the audio component).

I've built it many times, tried on another machine, studied the logs from the lib and they gave me this:

```
main Debug: creating access: rtsp://[myIp]/[nameofmyflux].mp4
main Debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 0 candidates
main Debug: no access modules matched with name rtsp
main Error: Your media can't be opened
```

I tried to rebuild the "plugin.dat", move it around the project files but never got any changes out of it.
I also tried the demo scenes provided with their scripts and i got the same result, i'm guessing my problem is linked to my build of the library or the output build of unity, but i don't know how to fix it.

Unity version is 2022.3.5 if it helps.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: share full logs of the standalone run

Comment: somehow libvlc is not finding the plugins, they might not be located near the libvlc.dll. They should. plugins is how libvlc works and if they cant be found, thats the problem

Comment: I kind of fixed it by dropping the vlc library folder into the data/plugins/x_86_64 folder of the build, it works, but i'm guessing i shouldn't need to do this every time i build?

In my project's asset folder the plugins are each in their respective folder, in a "plugins" folder who himself is in the same folder as the libvlcsharp DLL.

Comment: yes thats a bug. Please open a bug report at vlc-unity. Will fix